# How to get values checked by user in an array in python with Tkinter

Tags: python, tkinter

I'm beginning with Tkinter and Python, how can I add checked-boxes in a new array after the user clicks the button ? The type IntVar is not iterable and not hashable how can I  fix my problem ?

```
from tkinter import *

newarray=[]

def mget():
    variables = [var1, var2, var3, var4]
    #dict ={}
    #dict[var1]=var1
    print(var1.get(), var2.get() , var3.get())
    if(var1.get() == 1):
        newarray.extend(var1.get())


window = Tk()

#Variables initialisation
var1 = IntVar()
Checkbutton(window, text="one", variable = var1).grid(row=0, sticky=W)   
var2 = IntVar()
Checkbutton(window, text="two", variable = var2).grid(row=1, sticky=W)    
var3 = IntVar()
Checkbutton(window, text="three", variable = var3).grid(row=2, sticky=W)

#ButtonToGetCheckBoxesValues
Button(window, text="ZZZ", command=mget).grid(row=4, sticky=W)

window.mainloop()
```

I need to store values checked and submited by the user. Thank you

Comment: Read [how to use lists in Python](https://www.pythonforbeginners.com/lists/python-lists-cheat-sheet)

Answer (score 0):

If I understand correctly, you want something like this:

```
from tkinter import *

newarray=[]

def mget():

    print(var1.get(), var2.get() , var3.get())



window = Tk()

#Variables initialisation
var1 = IntVar()
Checkbutton(window, text="one", variable = var1, onvalue=1).grid(row=0, sticky=W)   
var2 = IntVar()
Checkbutton(window, text="two", variable = var2, onvalue=2).grid(row=1, sticky=W)    
var3 = IntVar()
Checkbutton(window, text="three", variable = var3, onvalue=3).grid(row=2, sticky=W)

#ButtonToGetCheckBoxesValues
Button(window, text="ZZZ", command=mget).grid(row=4, sticky=W)

window.mainloop()
```

Normally, a checkbutton's associated control variable will be set to 1 when it is set (on). You can supply an alternate value for the on state by setting onvalue to that value.